# Javassit: How to remove a superclass

Tags: bytecode, javassist

How do I remove a super class?

from

```
Foo extends Bar{
}
```

to

```
Foo{
}
```

Comment: You can't *remove* a superclass, as every Java class except `java.lang.Object` has a superclass. A declaration like `class Foo {}` is just a short-hand for `class Foo extends java.lang.Object {}`. So if you want that, you have *set* the super class to `java.lang.Object`.

Comment: Yes, you are right, thanks for your answer